# creating a dropdown PHP quiz using arrays and loops

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I would like to know how I would use php arrays and loops to direct users to an answer page (depending on how they answer each question), my quiz looks something like this:

```
<form action="results.php" method="post">
<p class="question">What club am I in?</p>
            <select name="club">
                <option value="0">Club Soccer</option>
                <option value="1">Pandora Dance Troupe</option>
                <option value="2">Colleges Against Cancer</option>
                <option value="3">Engineering Ambassadors</option>
                <option value="4">Photo Society</option>
            </select>
        <br/>
        <div>
            <p class="question">what is my favorite thing?</p>
        </div>
            <select name="favorites">
                <option value="0">Sushi</option>
                <option value="1">Chocolate</option>
                <option value="2">hip hop music</option>
                <option value="3">Dolphins</option>
                <option value="4">My Dog</option>
            </select>
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"/>
        </form>
        <br/><br/>
```

Comment: I'm afraid we're not here to write that code for you... Show what you have tried, and we'll be happy to help debug it. If you haven't tried anything, do that first.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the usage of php arrays for building your dropdowns does not have anything to do with the redirection of the user. As you see in your example code there is the action attribute of the form element that gives the target the user get's to once he hits the submit button.

If you want to dynamically change the action attribute when a selection is made you need to utilize Javascript.

One possible solution would also be to redirect by header() when evaluating the $_POST variable at results.php, but I would not recommend this.